# Windows 10: How to Bind 4-Finger Left/Right Swipe Gesture to Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, touchpad

I'm a Windows 10 user that makes frequent use of the Remote Desktop function for work, and would like to know if there is a way to map the touchpad's 4-finger swipe gestures to a keyboard shortcut.

I need to quickly switch between my Remote Desktop app and my own desktop, and have found that the "Ctrl + Windows + Left/Right" keyboard shortcut only allows me to switch between desktops IN THE REMOTE PC, whereas the four-finger left/right swipe on my laptop allows me to switch between the desktops ON MY LAPTOP, which is exactly what I need to quickly switch between the desktop containing the Remote Desktop app and the desktop with my other programs open. However, when I working from my laptop at my workstation, I can't access my touchpad conveniently.

Given that there appears to be a difference between what exactly the "Ctrl + Windows + Left/Right" shortcut and the four-finger left/right swipe gestures do, is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to perform the four-finger left/right swipe gestures, so that I can continue switching between my laptop's desktops while remoting?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be more the job of the mouse software developper? https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360048575453-Bind-button-to-four-finger-swipe-gesture-instead-of-CTRL-WIN-Arrows-to-switch-desktops

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stumble across a solution that I can confirm works for Windows 10 (this was a while ago, and I am unable to replicate my search and find the source of my information, sorry).

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> can be used to first highlight the desktop of the PC you are working on, which will then allow to swipe between the different virtual desktops that you've set up, if any.